# simulate key press in selenium webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriverJS to write a test. Now I need to press the key down in keyboard. Is it possible to simulate key press on the selenium webdriverJS ?
if yes how ?

In java we do this :

```
driver.findElement(Locator).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37392949/1478566

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve that by an ActionSequence.
There are several functions, but keyDown(key) and keyUp(key) are only used for modifier keys. The one you need is sendKeys(...var_args)

```
var element1 = driver.findElement(<locator1>);
driver.actions().click(element1).sendKeys(Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

You can even pass multiple keys

```
var element2 = driver.findElement(<locator2>);
driver.actions().click(element2).sendKeys(Array(3).fill(Key.ARROW_UP), Key.ENTER).perform();
```

A complete list for all possible Keys you can find here:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Key.html

For more details just read here:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_LegacyActionSequence.html

Comment: Your second link is broken. It has been moved to https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_LegacyActionSequence.html. ActionSequence has been deprecated and will be replaced by Actions https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/input_exports_Actions.html

Comment: ty for your advice, changed the second link

Answer (score 1):

Med.J - update your code as below:

```
    Robot robot3 = new Robot();
    robot3.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
    robot3.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, try it in this way:

```
new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver).
    keyDown(webdriver.Key.SHIFT).
    click(element1).
    click(element2).
    dragAndDrop(element3, element4).
    keyUp(webdriver.Key.SHIFT).
    perform();
```

For more keys have a look at

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions.js#L43

Unfortunately there is no `ARROW_DOWN` key as you can see

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to press arrows down so i must chang SHIFT by what ?

Comment: use ARROW_DOWN and for more help use http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/enum_webdriver_Key.html

Comment: ARROW_DOWN does not work for me it give me an InvalidArgumentError: Not a modifier key

Answer (score 0):

for down arrow click, use below:

```
keys('Down arrow');
```

Comment: I want to press Arrow_DOWN in Selenium WebDriverJS

Comment: I m using  selenium webdriver js (for node.js not java )