# Selenium webdriver (javascript) tab out

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While filling out a form the test needs to tab out in order to go to next field.

The error I get is:

```
 InvalidArgumentError: Not a modifier key
```

Code:

```
var key = require('selenium-webdriver').Key;
var actionSequence = require('selenium-webdriver').ActionSequence;

    new actionSequence(driver).keyDown(key.CONTROL).keyDown(key.TAB).perform().then(function(){
    console.log("Done selection?");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keyDown` action is only for modifier keys :

```js
key.CONTROL
key.SHIFT
key.ALT
key.COMMAND
```

To send the tab key, use `.sendKeys`:

```js
var key = require('selenium-webdriver').Key;
var actionSequence = require('selenium-webdriver').ActionSequence;

new actionSequence(driver).keyDown(key.CONTROL).sendKeys(key.TAB).perform().then(function(){
    console.log("Done selection?");
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I used sendKeys instead of keyDown. But the test does not tab out and tires to click on element that is greyed out.             (InvalidElementStateError: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions)

Comment: Why are you pressing the Control key? Have you tried to just press `Tab` instead of `Ctrl+Tab`. Note that to get the previous element, the short-cut is `Shift+Tab`.